# Connected Android device - brings the network down?

Tags: networking, linux-mint, kde, devices, android

I have dealt with sensitive development under Android, and have recently decided to switch to Linux now sit under (Mint 13 - KDE).
But strangely, when the Android device is connected, my network goes down and only reboot works.

I tried

```
sudo service network-manager stop
sudo service network-manager start
```

And this udev rule for the Android device.

```
vim /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
SUBSYSTEM == "usb", ATTR {idVendor} == "04e8", MODE = "0666", GROUP = "plugdev"
chmod a + r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

Here is an article
http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

But with this article, when I try to connect as a drive, I don't know how to mount it. I did this: http://blog.mpshouse.com/?p=609

Basically, **I want the device to work without bringing down my network**

What is the cause, what is the problem, what's wrong?

Comment: So your network stop functioning when you connect an Android device? Run `ifconfig -a` when the problem is present and post the output. Some devices, if USB tethering is enabled, is seen as a USB network adapter. If this happens and it is added as the default route, network connectivity would be broken while it is connected.